# Get similar queries from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make a query to get only records with the same `screen_name` and `skip`=0 value?

```
---------------------------
| id | screen_name | skip |
---------------------------
| 1  | mary        | 0    |
| 2  | john        | 0    |
| 3  | tom         | 1    |
| 4  | mary        | 0    |
| 5  | ben         | 1    |
| 6  | john        | 1    |
---------------------------
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please provide the wanted result in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coud try to use:

```
select id,screen_name,skip
  from TABLE
 where skip=0
   and screen_name in (select t2.screen_name
                         from TABLE t2
                     group by t2.screen_name
                    having count(*)>1 
                      )
```

This will give you all the records with skip=0 and a repeated screen_name

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  screen_Name
FROM    tableName
WHERE   skip = 0
GROUP   BY screen_name
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d86/1)

**UPDATE**

if you want to get all records not just the `screen_name`, use `JOIN` instead of `IN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  screen_Name
            FROm    tableName
            WHERE   skip = 0
            GROUP   BY screen_name
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b ON a.screen_name = b.screen_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50d86/2)

For faster performance, add an `INDEX` on column `screen_name` for faster performance.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX index_name (screen_Name)
```